# Как можно изменить содержимое коллекции ListView в виджете при нажатии на один из элементов коллекции?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, виджет, android-widgets

Создал пустое приложение, добавил класс, который наследует от AppWidgetProvider.

В xml файле добавил ListView, заполнил данную коллекцию в классе, наследующем от RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.

Собственно при нажатии на один из элементов ListView выводится соответствующее уведомление.

**Factory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory**

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.item);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.itemText, donors.get(position).getName());
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Provider.ITEM_POSITION, position);
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.itemText, intent);

    return remoteView;
}
```

**Provider extends AppWidgetProvider**

```
final static String ITEM_POSITION = "item_position";
final static String ACTION_ON_CLICK = "com.example.admin.widgetlistview.itemonclick";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_ON_CLICK)) {
        int itemPos = intent.getIntExtra(ITEM_POSITION, -1);
        if (itemPos != -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on item " + itemPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int i : appWidgetIds) {
        updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, i);
    }
}

void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                  int appWidgetId) {
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget);

    setListClick(rv, context, appWidgetId);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId,
            R.id.listView);
}

void setListClick(RemoteViews rv, Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(context, MyProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_ON_CLICK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            intent, 0);
    rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listView, pendingIntent);
}
```

Необходимо при нажатии на элемент ListView изменить значение данного элемента.
Как это можно реализовать?